# How to import library into Dart in AndroidStudio

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to import [translator](https://pub.dev/packages/translator/install) into a project on AndroidStudio.

I ran this command in the terminal:

```
flutter pub add translator
```

Then I added this line in the code:

```
import 'package: translator / translator.dart';
```

but I get an error message:

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist:
'package: language_tool / language_tool.dart'.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: there is spaces in the import

Comment: open your` pubspec.yaml`, you can see if there is this `translator` package under your dependencies. If not, something went wrong.

Try to run `flutter pub get` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the package is under my dependencies

Comment: can you share your code? both of `pubspec.yaml` and the one on the page where you added the package definition?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE]" and all their linked pages. Your question doesn't show any effort toward finding a solution yourself, which it should. As is it looks like you didn't try and want us to fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First restart your IDE , if does not work   than do this commands.
This worked for me in  VS Code. I only had to run these lines in my terminal/command prompt and problem was solved.

```
flutter packages get
```

Optionally you also run.

`flutter upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem, when I run the script I get this line before printing the results
lib / translator.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package: hello_world / translator.dart'.

Do you know if this is a problem? and how can i fix it?

Comment: great you got it!!!!

Comment: You dont't have to worry about above warning, you will not face any issue while developint but still you want to know about it than read this,https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37978#:~:text=You%20can%20launch%20a%20lib,is%20fixing%20that%20for%20you).